# How do I find out which process is listening on a socket on windows server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003

Whenever I try to run an test.exe from command prompt, I get an error **

> test.exe: binding connection listen
>   socket to TCP port *7963*
>   failed: 10048 (Specified address is in
>   use).

So, how do I find out which process is using the specified port?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`netstat -ano` will get you a list of PIDs by port.  Feel free to add fancy filtering if you can't be bothered to look through the list;)  Then just turn on the PID column in Task Manager and identify the culprit.

Comment: @phoebus: Thanks for the answer. Sorry I can't vote for the answer. I did get the PID from the netstat command. But, now if I want to force close a port. Is it possible?

Comment: Once you correlate that PID with the PID list in Task Manager, just close the application that is using the port, or change its settings to use a different one.